# Trouble with svg scripting

Tags: scripting, svg, ecmascript-5

I'm trying to get some basic ecma scripting to work in an svg document that I have.

```
<svg contentScriptType="text/ecmascript" width="957px"
     xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" zoomAndPan="magnify"
     contentStyleType="text/css" viewBox="-2998 -1920 6580 5780" height="841px"
     preserveAspectRatio="xMidYMid meet" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
     version="1.1" onload="init(evt)"">

<script type = "text/ecmascript">
    <![CDATA[
        function init(evt) {
            if (window.svgDocument == null) {
                svgDoc = evt.target.ownerDocument;
            }
        }

        function displayName(name) {
            svgDoc.getElementById("node_name").firstChild.data = name;
        }
    ]]> </script>

<text class = "label" id = "node_name" x="10" y="390"></text>

<circle fill-opacity="0.2" fill="#3ccb5d" r="40.0" cx="1568.2628"
class="46960" cy="-1518.6278" stroke="#000000"
stroke-opacity="0.5" stroke-width="1.0" 
onmouseover="displayName('Showing Nodes')"/>
</svg>
```

For some reason though, every time I try to fire the displayName event from the circle, I get a "Cannot set property "data" of null" on the last line of my svg tag (onload="init(evt)"), and I'm not entirely sure why. Thoughts?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should really use textContent, that will work whether the node has children or not e.g.

```
function displayName(name) {
    svgDoc.getElementById("node_name").textContent = name;
}
```

Comment: Oh, awesome. Thanks for the tip. Any idea where to find good documentation for svg scripting?

Comment: http://www.w3.org/Graphics/SVG/IG/resources/svgprimer.html is a good start for all things SVG

Answer (score 0):

Okay, so I managed to figure out the answer to this, but it's counter-intuitive enough that I feel like I should really post it up here. Apparently the reason this wouldn't work is because if there is nothing between the text tag its data is treated as null instead of just empty.

```
Broken Code:    
    <text class = "label" id = "node_name" x="10" y="390"></text>
    getElementById('node_name').firstChild == null

Working Code:
    <text class = "label" id = "node_name" x="10" y="390"> </text>
    getElementById('node_name').firstChild == " "
```